# Write XML data into XML file

Tags: ruby, xml

I want ot implement very simple example of XML file. I tested this example:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8') do |xml|
    xml.root {
     xml.products {
      xml.widget {
       xml.id_ "10"
       xml.name "Awesome widget"
      }
     }
    }
   end
   puts builder.to_xml
   file = File.new("builder.xml", "w")
```

But when I open the XML file it's empty. How I can write the XML content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this:

```
File.open('builder.xml', 'w') do |file|
    file << builder.to_xml
end
```